# How do I pass DecimalFormat two literal characters in a row?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I want to format the number 1234.5678 as ($1,234.57)

So I am passing in the formatting string '(''$'#,##0.00')'

But that gives me ('$1,234.57)

I'm guessing the two apostrophes are being changed to a literal ' and the ' after the $ is being eaten.

So How can I put the string ($ into the pattern?

Comment: Try DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("($#,##0.00)"); it should work

Comment: @DonatasD Is any character not listed in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html treated literally?

Comment: I think what happens is '(''$' transforms to '('$', as in javadocs 
```To create a single quote itself, use two in a row: "# o''clock".```
So, to avoid quote you should change '(''$' => '($' as it seems multiple symbol prefixes should be within same '
```Used to quote special characters in a prefix or suffix, for example, "'#'#" formats 123 to "#123". To create a single quote itself, use two in a row: "# o''clock```

Comment: @DonatasD What If I wanted "## 123" (yeah - why?). So that would be '#''#' # - but that would be the same problem. Is this a limit of DecimalFormat?

Comment: You would need to write it as "'##' #", where ## would be special characters

Comment: @DonatasD - thank you. I was thinking the ' was for a character (how Java works) instead of quoting a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, `($` and `)` are not treated like special character by the `DecimalFormat` since they have no meaning inside of an expression.

If you'd use `#` for example, then it would make sense to use `'#'`

See the Javadoc

> ' Used to quote special characters in a prefix or
>   suffix, for example, "'#'#" formats 123 to "#123". To create a single
>   quote itself, use two in a row: "# o''clock".

The following works perfect

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("($#,##0.00)");
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(1234.5678)); // ($1,234.57)
```